# JavaFX always turns nodes in the same direction in a RotateTransition

Tags: animation, javafx, rotation

I want to rotate a JavaFX node 90 degrees in an animation along the y-axis.

```
public void rotateNode(Node node)
{
    RotateTransition rotateTransition = new RotateTransition(Duration.seconds(3), node);
    rotateTransition.setAxis(Rotate.Y_AXIS);
    rotateTransition.setFromAngle(0);
    rotateTransition.setToAngle(90);
    rotateTransition.play();
}
```

That works fine, but actually I want the node to turn in the opposite direction so -90 degrees.
That's why I changed the line:

```
rotateTransition.setToAngle(90);
```

to

```
rotateTransition.setToAngle(-90);
```

but the node is still turning in the same direction.

Does somebody has any idea how to slove this problem.
Thanks

Comment: Works for me... You need to use a 3d scene of course, since you're not rotating around the z axis...

Comment: OK, thanks when I use a PerspectiveCamera then it works.